# Image inside grid won't display rounded corners

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a LazyVGrid containing an image

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct AlbumGridView: View {
    let columns = Array(repeating: GridItem(.flexible(), spacing: 15), count: 2)

    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            LazyVGrid(columns: columns, spacing: 20) {
                Image(uiImage: UIImage(contentsOfFile: "/path/to/image.heic")!)
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
                    .cornerRadius(6.0)
            }
        }
}
```

The corner radius is not visible though. When I add a frame of fixed width and height, it only works when the width and height are not equal. How to fix this?

Comment: Works fine here, Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5, at least with image from assets. Maybe it's image dependent? Try different variants.

Comment: @Asperi You were right! This seems to happen with HEIC images but not JPG ones